# Extracting optional parameter value from url on angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am redirecting to my Angular2 site with some (optional) appended parameters like so:

```
https://my-site.com/?param1=some-value1&param2=some-value2
```

So i want to extract the values into variables if they exist:

```
let value1 = extractValueByParam(url, param1Str);
```

Can it be done with router variables? Or what is the "correct" way of doing this?

So far the best method I have found is to use window.location.href value and parse it myself, but it does not seem like the right thing to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `queryParams`:

```js
constructor (private _ar: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this._ar.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params)); // params used with '/'
   this._ar.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params)); // optional params used with '?'/'&'
}
```

official docs:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, I see that the percentage signs (%) are being replaced with '/' in queryParams , how do I keep these percentage signs as i need to carry them forward for the BE

Comment: which percentage signs? don't know the internal logic, maybe its a bug within angular..

Comment: Just so this does not confuse anyone, I was wrong by looking at string value vs UUID value.

Answer (score 0):

In your ngModules set the rout as:

```
{path: '/:param1/:param2', component: YourComponent}
```

Then in your component, get the value with the following:

```
 if(params['param1']){
    var param1 = params['param1'];
 }
```

Comment: But my url is not of this form, how would this match? to be specific, I do not have '/' between params.

Comment: Also getting this error: Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '/:token': path cannot start with a slash ;